# Check Geometries Plugin - attribute value in results

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geometry

What does the real value of Sliver polygon represent?

- it's not the area of the polygon
- it's not the perimeter
- is not the area of the bounding box

so I ask if anyone can tell me what it represents, I can't find anything useful in the documentation.

[image]

https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html#geometry-checker-plugin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it is the value of the "thinness" parameter

[image]